# How can i found out the workspaces that an user has acces to

Tags: workspace, podio

I have integrated podio user authentification, and now I have to found out the  workspaces that an user has acces to.
Is there a function for that ?

With PodioUserStatus::get() I can only retrive part of the information related to the user, but not the workspaces he has access to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `get_organisations` method which is described here: https://developers.podio.com/doc/organizations/get-organizations-22344